# jquery events for dynamically adding content

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery autocomplete function to enhance the user-friendliness of my site. It works really well and gives it a nice feel. But, what I'm trying to do right now is have jquery dynamically fadeIn an additional input tag based upon the values of the previous two input tags.

Since the client doesn't actually click on the input tag when using the autocomplete function (they click on the li tag instead), I need to find a jquery event that will detect the change of the value of what's in the input field. If the user clicks on the drop down list to fill in the input field, the user isn't clicking on the input field, they're clicking on the li tag.

I've tried using the .click event for the l> tag that the user clicks on to trigger the fading in of an additional input tag, but it doesn't work.

Any thoughts, guys?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery's in-house [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), than you can make use of its **select** or **change** event.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Could you explain that a bit more, though?

Comment: **Select Event**: Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to the selected item. The default action of select is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item. Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the menu from closing.

**Change Event**: After an item was selected; ui.item refers to the selected item. Always triggered after the close event.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Also, you can dig more into jQuery autocomplete by using the demos at [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete). Make use of right side tabs and see the source by clicking **View Source**. You can dig more by clicking bottom tabs for extra information.

Comment: do you think that perhaps you could give me some sample code to demonstrate this concept in action?

Answer (score 0):

Read `.live`

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/live)

FROM jQuery

---

> The .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants.

Comment: though you have not paste any code, so i suggest you to read this.

Comment: well, i really don't know where to start with this one. So, I haven't written any effective jquery code yet.